# Filter each parameters value from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, arraylist

I want to find a mean to **filter** all each keyword from my [API call result](https://jsfiddle.net/BMF_T95/5kqycpav/1/) who i storing in my list:

```
const jList = []; 

result.data.results.forEach((element) => {
   jList.push(element)
});
```

That my api url call but it dosen't have parameters value i wanted :

h..s://api/...&results_per_page=20&what=%22lead-manager%22&content-type=application/json%22

...but i saw they are present directly on [API call result](https://jsfiddle.net/BMF_T95/5kqycpav/1/), so i trying this to getting each parameters like : `title` , `company` unfortunately it not working

```
for (element of jobList) {
  
  title: { result.data.results.[].title },
  created: { result.data.results.[].created  },
  description: { result.data.results.[].description  },
  company: { result.data.results.[].company  }
 
}
  console.log(title)
```

How i can get each parameters from element ??

So please help me, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result.data.results.map((item) =>{
        let info = {
        title: item.title
        description: item.description

    }})
```

i don't exactly understand what you want to achieve but is this what you want ?

Comment: he is exactly what i'm talking about, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

did you try using map ?

```
result.data.results.map((item) =>{ console.log(item.title) })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks it working good but how i can make it so that for exemple the `title` match the same `result` bloc of `company`, `created` etc...
??

Comment: i don't really understand what you want , you can now access all fields.